# Push Notification exception in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, apple-push-notifications

I am developing Xamarin forms application, I have enabled the Push notification process for sending the updates for my app to the users. I have used the amazon SNS tool to integrate the sending of messages to the installed users of my application. I have followed procedure mentioned in below link,

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforxamarin/developerguide/sns-send-push-notifications-ios.html

When I checked the push notification functionality in my application, it worked fine in Android. But it did not work in iOS devices, when I debugged the source I found that the exception occurred in registering the Device ID in the application created for my application in amazon. Please find the issue I have got below.

**Error: The type initializer for 'Amazon.CognitoIdentity.AmazonCognitoIdentityConfig' threw an exception**, when creating application end point

**Code Snippet:**

```
var response = await SnsClient.CreatePlatformEndpointAsync(
    new CreatePlatformEndpointRequest {
      Token = deviceToken,
      PlatformApplicationArn = "YourPlatformArn" /* insert your platform application ARN here */
    });
```

**Note:** Got exception while debug in above line.

I have also updated my amazon related assemblies in my projects but still facing this issue. Please let me know if you require any details and let me know on how to resolve this.

**Exception Stack Trace:**

Amazon.CognitoIdentity.AmazonCognitoIdentityClient..ctor(Amazon.Runtime.AWSCredentials credentials, Amazon.RegionEndpoint region) <0x1012398e0 + 0x0002f> in <06884ea796b447418aeb283bf2a6e476#045e7beb7af13e2ec8fd854c23958>:0 at Amazon.CognitoIdentity.CognitoAWSCredentials..ctor (System.String accountId, System.String identityPoolId, System.String unAuthRoleArn, System.String authRoleArn, Amazon.RegionEndpoint region) <0x1012354e0 + 0x0005b> in <06884ea796b447418aeb283bf286e476#045e7347beb7af13e2ec8fd854c23958>:0 at Amazon.CognitoIdentity.CognitoAWSCredentials..ctor (Sytem.String identityPoolId, Amazon.RegionEndpoint region) <0x01012354a0 + 0x0002f> in <06884ea796b447418aeb283bf2a6e476#045e7beb7af13e2ec8fd854c23958>:0 at ShowCaseSample.Models.AmazonUtils.get_Credentials () <0x1004327d0 + 00063> in :0 at ShowCaseSample.Models.AmazonUtils.get_SnsClient () <0x100432870 + 0x0001f> in :0 at ShowCaseSample.Models.AmazonUtils +d_14.MoveNext () <0x100532b20 + 0x0048f> in :0

Regards,

Cheran

Comment: Have you enabled the SDK logging? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforxamarin/developerguide/setup.html#set-logging Can you post as well how you create the credential for AmazonSimpleNotificationServiceClient?

Comment: Created credential for AmazonSimpleNotificationServiceClient as mentioned in below link,
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforxamarin/developerguide/sns-send-push-notifications-ios.html#create-an-sns-client

My Code :
AWSCredentials Credentials = new CognitoAWSCredentials(IdentityPoolId, RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
IAmazonSimpleNotificationService snsClient = new AmazonSimpleNotificationServiceClient(Credentials, RegionEndpoint.USEast1);

I have referred below link to create identity pool id,
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/identity-pools.html

Comment: Also find stack trace of exception,